# wpf mvvm two way databinding with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have classes generated by Entity Framework as follows. My requirement is to load data from the database into a List View and if any checked changes happen in the List View, store it back.

For that purpose in my model, I have written another partial class as below that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I want to use my Entity Framework classes as models.

Along the same lines I have a view containing a List View for displaying `Name` and `Location` and a check box for each row to display checked state.  So for the checkbox, an example of the logic I have written is `CheckBox IsChecked=true`,`mode=two way`,`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.  I use a `OnCheckedChanged` event to call `db.SaveChanges` in my view model.

`db` is object of type `SampleDbContext`. But it seems the binding is not happening,  i.e. checked changes are not stored into the database.

Why are checked changes not saving to the database?

Entity Framework classes:

```
public partial class Datagrid
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsChecked { get; set; }
}

public partial class SampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleDbContext() : base("name=SampleDbContext")
    {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Datagrid> Datagrids { get; set; }
}
```

My Custom Class in the Models: (This is a sample code may have some spelling mistakes but please ignore it)

```
[MetaDataType(typeof(grid))]
public partial class DataGrid
{}

public class grid:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Nullable<bool> IsChecked 
    {   
        get { return IsChecked; }
        set
        {
            IsChecked=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }   

    //INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same Property within your property setter.  IsChecked=value.  Create a private field to store the isChecked value.

```
[MetaDataType(typeof(grid))]
public partial class DataGrid
{
}

public class grid:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool? m_IsChecked;
    public Nullable<bool> IsChecked  
    get
    {
        return m_IsChecked;
    }
    set
    {
        if(m_IsChecked != value)
        {
            m_IsChecked=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I create a private field like that I get an error like No mappable property for IsChecked

Comment: Your getter doesn't look right.  Shouldn't it be `return m_IsChecked;`?